# Which is cheaper in Europe - traveling by converted van or airbnb hopping?

Tags: europe, long-term, airbnb, campers

My partner and I are planning to travel Europe for a year, spending 2 - 4 weeks in every destination and exploring as much as we can. We'll be working remotely, so we want to keep everything as cheap and convenient as possible. If you've ever travelled in a converted van, or spent a long time Airbnb & hostel hopping, I'd really love some opinions on which might be cheaper. Have been looking around, but comparisons and proper advice are surprisingly hard to come by.

If we do go with airbnbing, we'll catch cheap flights with just our backpacks and do a lot of hitchhiking. And with the van, we'd put about a month of work into it, and keep it as low-budget as possible.

Comment: What is "better" is impossible to answer objectively because it depends on your personal preferences. Try narrowing down your question to something that can receive a fact-based answer.

Comment: Thank you TooTea, I've changed it to cheaper, as I think that's a good place to start.

Comment: "And with the van, we'd put about a month of work into it, and keep it as low-budget as possible." - do you mean that you would spend one month converting a regular van to something that is habitable?

Comment: A van will give you more flexibility and need less planning ahead. If you arrive in a place you don't like, you can move on (or back) a bit. You can still take a BnB now and then when you feel like you need more space and a proper bed.

Comment: Impossible to answer, even when restricted to 'cheaper', as there are lots of different price options for vans, hostels and other options to stay and cost of staying somewhere in a van. But please check out you can stay in Europe (and work) for a year. Most people are restricted to 90 days out of each 180 days, and working is often not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a van, too many *cons* to it.

Gas is expensive, might be difficult to find overnight parking and/or amenities like showers and bathroom, and might be difficult to setup a consistent internet (you say you work remotely) and power your devices ... and eating and ...

If parking is available, it will probably be outside of city centers or be expensive; making it not fun to walk/cab/bus to and from nice places.

Short term rental is the best solution in your case, you can safely drop your stuff at the location, have a nice base to visit around; you will be able to better manage your food requirements (make a decent grocery visit), and apartments will also have laundry and maybe better internet access.

Comment: My comment was the opposite: it's a matter of opinion.